# FB Share always displays "Object Moved" for Urls that do redirection

Tags: facebook-sharer

I can't seem to figure out as to why the Facebook share link would always show Object Moved.

Here is the url:
https://stage.registernow.com.au/secure/Register.aspx?E=33190

Here is the result in the Sharing Debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.registernow.com.au%2Fsecure%2FRegister.aspx%3FE%3D33190

On my register.aspx and registrationtype.aspx pages, I had specified already the necessary meta tags. But it keeps on having the error: The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

On the Url link, if you get to access it, it would do a redirect to a certain page (registrationtype.aspx) and this is on purpose as part of our business rules.

Thanks for any help/tips!

EDIT: 
some links would work like:
https://stage.registernow.com.au/secure/register.aspx?e=33068

The link directly above doesn't do any redirects so it would display the description, title, image, basically every meta tags that have been specified.